# Using Javascript to Show HTML elements based on Days of the week, and Time of the day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching for a while, and tried many scripts to get the following rule to work on my website:

On Sunday 12 - 24, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday show this:

"Order today for delivery on Friday"

On Thursday 12 - 24, Friday, Saturday show this:

"Order today for delivery on Monday"

On Thursday 0 - 12, Sunday 0 - 12 show this:

"Order by 12pm for delivery tomorrow"

The script I have created is this:

```js
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
if (CurrentDay !== 1) {
  $('#del_fri').toggle();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 2) {
  $('#del_fri').toggle();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 3) {
  $('#del_fri').toggle();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 4) {
  $('#del_fri').toggle();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 5) {
  $('#del_mon').toggle();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 6) {
  $('#del_mon').toggle();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 7) {
  $('#del_mon').toggle();
}
```

```css
#del_mon,
#del_fri,
#del_tom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="del_mon">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Monday.</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_fri">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Friday</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_tom">
  <h4>Order by 12pm today for delivery tomorrow!</h4>
</div>
```

Apologies for my lack of knowledge in Javascript, this is the best I could come up with after my research.

I know there is a "getHours" function I can use for specifying the 0 - 12 and 12 - 24 time frames, but I could not work out how to add it.

Any help/direction would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `.toggle()` will show/hide matched elements. I suppose you do not need that.. `getDay()` will return values _from 0 to 6_

Comment: Thanks Rayon, would you recommend using .show() instead?

Comment: I would recommend using one div here because you will mostly likely want the structure to be exactly the same for all cases. You can use the `$('.order-eta').html(myText);` to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
if ((CurrentDay == 0 && Now.getHours()>12) || CurrentDay == 1 || CurrentDay == 2 || CurrentDay == 3) {
$('#del_fri').show();
} 
else if ((CurrentDay == 3 && Now.getHours()>12) || CurrentDay == 4 || CurrentDay == 5) {
$('#del_mon').show();
}
else {
$('#del_tom').show();
}
```

```css
#del_mon,
#del_fri,
#del_tom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="del_mon">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Monday.</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_fri">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Friday</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_tom">
  <h4>Order by 12pm today for delivery tomorrow!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @nitha, your solution works great here, but I am just trying to implement it on my site with no luck yet - i'll keep trying as I have probably made a simple error somewhere.

Comment: Hi @Nitha, I tried implementing this solution, but nothing I tried it working. I have a screenshot of my implementation that I think should work. Can you offer any advice? http://i64.tinypic.com/2hztop2.png

Comment: Add the script inside $( document ).ready(function() { // add script here})

Answer (score 0):

> *The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date*(Not 1-7)
>
> Use `.show()` instead of `.toggle()`, Though that is not causing an issue but does not make any sense either.

```js
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
if (CurrentDay !== 0) {
  $('#del_fri').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 1) {
  $('#del_fri').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 2) {
  $('#del_fri').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 3) {
  $('#del_fri').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 4) {
  $('#del_mon').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 5) {
  $('#del_mon').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 6) {
  $('#del_mon').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 6 && Now.getHours()>12) {
  $('#del_fri').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 6 && Now.getHours()< 12) {
  $('#del_tom').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 3 && Now.getHours()> 12) {
  $('#del_mon').show();
} else if (CurrentDay !== 3 && Now.getHours()< 12) {
  $('#del_tom').show();
}
```

```css
#del_mon,
#del_fri,
#del_tom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="del_mon">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Monday.</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_fri">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Friday</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_tom">
  <h4>Order by 12pm today for delivery tomorrow!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @rayon, That works well for displaying the message for the correct day :) 
I will just add a new variable for `Now.getHours()` and make that a condition in the Thursday (3) and Sunday (6) days.

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing what causes `#del_tom` to be shown, but this is much more concise:

```
var CurrentDay = (new Date()).getDay();

switch(CurrentDay) {
   case (CurrentDay < 5):
     $('#del_fri').toggle();
     break;
   default:
     $('#del_mon').toggle();
     break;
}
```

You can add whatever case you need to cover `#del_tom`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Now = new Date();
var CurrentDay = Now.getDay();
var CurrentHrs = Now.getHours();
if (CurrentDay < 5 && (CurrentHrs >= 12 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {
  $('.msg').hide()
  $('#del_fri').show();
} else if (CurrentDay < 7 && (CurrentHrs >= 12 && CurrentHrs <= 24)) {  
  $('.msg').hide()
  $('#del_mon').show();
} else if((CurrentDay == 4 || CurrentDay == 7) && (CurrentHrs >= 0 && CurrentHrs < 12)){   
  $('.msg').hide()
  $('#del_tom').show();
}else{
  $('.msg').hide()
  $('#no_del').show();  
}
```

```css
.msg {
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="del_mon" class="msg">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Monday.</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_fri" class="msg">
  <h4>Order today for delivery on Friday</h4>
</div>
<div id="del_tom" class="msg">
  <h4>Order by 12pm today for delivery tomorrow!</h4>
</div>
<div id="no_del" class="msg">
  <h4>You can not order now!</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Mohammed - I appreciate your time

Answer (score 0):

Check this working snippet. You can change internal html dynamically.

```js
 var date = new Date(); //get current date

 var day = date.getDay(); // getDay returns 0 to 6; 0 = sun, 1 = mon and so on.
 var hour= date.getHours(); // gethhours returns the hour (0-23)


//On Sunday 12 - 24, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
// Check day between 0 to 3 & time  between  (12-24 )

  
  if ( (day <= 3) && (hour >= 12) ) { 
       
   var result = "Order today for delivery on Friday";
    } 


//On Thursday 12 - 24, Friday, Saturday
else if ( (day >= 4) && (hour >= 12) ){
 
        var result = "Order today for delivery on Monday";
    }

//On Thursday 0 - 12, Sunday 0 - 12 (means between 24 hours and 12 hours)

else if ( (day == 4 || day == 0) && (hour == 0 || hour >= 12) ) { 
         
        var result = "Order by 12pm for delivery tomorrow";
   }
   
else{
         var result = "No details available";
}


//outut the result to div
  document.getElementById("order").innerHTML = result;
```

```css
#order{
  background:red;
  color:yellow;
  padding:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="order">
 </div>
```